# replace client’s id with their respective name in shipment dictionary using a loop and dictionary comprehension

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

d1={101:{'Sender':1,'Receiver':3,'Start date':'14-03-2020','Delivery date':'25-03-2020','Sender location':'Area 1','Receiver location':'Area 6','Delivery status':'Delivered','Shipping cost':198},
102:{'Sender':4,'Receiver':1,'Start date':'18-06-2020','Delivery date':'09-07-2020','Sender location':'Area 2','Receiver location':'Area 4','Delivery status':'Delivered','Shipping cost':275},
103:{'Sender':2,'Receiver':3,'Start date':'01-12-2020','Delivery date':'Null','Sender location':'Area 5','Receiver location':'Area 1','Delivery status':'In Transit','Shipping cost':200},
104:{'Sender':1,'Receiver':5,'Start date':'23-06-2020','Delivery date':'25-06-2020','Sender location':'Area 1','Receiver location':'Area 4','Delivery status':'Delivered','Shipping cost':314},
105:{'Sender':3,'Receiver':4,'Start date':'29-08-2020','Delivery date':'10-09-2020','Sender location':'Area 5','Receiver location':'Area 3','Delivery status':'Delivered','Shipping cost':275},
106:{'Sender':5,'Receiver':2,'Start date':'28-06-2020','Delivery date':'Null','Sender location':'Area 3','Receiver location':'Area 1','Delivery status':'In Transit','Shipping cost':270}}

d2 = {1:'Phillip',2:'Omega lll',3 :'Ramya',4:'Romesh',5:'John'}

Comment: Show your expected output.  Is your client ID the same as the value for 'Receiver' in d1? Do you want 'Receiver':3 to change to 'Receiver': 'Ramya'? What have you tried?

Comment: I want to replace Sender and Receiver Id with their client name. Client name is given in d2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop through the first dictionary and replace the id with their name from the second dictionary, if the id is in the second dictionary:

```
d1={101:{'Sender':1,'Receiver':3,'Start date':'14-03-2020','Delivery date':'25-03-2020','Sender location':'Area 1','Receiver location':'Area 6','Delivery status':'Delivered','Shipping cost':198}, 102:{'Sender':4,'Receiver':1,'Start date':'18-06-2020','Delivery date':'09-07-2020','Sender location':'Area 2','Receiver location':'Area 4','Delivery status':'Delivered','Shipping cost':275}, 103:{'Sender':2,'Receiver':3,'Start date':'01-12-2020','Delivery date':'Null','Sender location':'Area 5','Receiver location':'Area 1','Delivery status':'In Transit','Shipping cost':200}, 104:{'Sender':1,'Receiver':5,'Start date':'23-06-2020','Delivery date':'25-06-2020','Sender location':'Area 1','Receiver location':'Area 4','Delivery status':'Delivered','Shipping cost':314}, 105:{'Sender':3,'Receiver':4,'Start date':'29-08-2020','Delivery date':'10-09-2020','Sender location':'Area 5','Receiver location':'Area 3','Delivery status':'Delivered','Shipping cost':275}, 106:{'Sender':5,'Receiver':2,'Start date':'28-06-2020','Delivery date':'Null','Sender location':'Area 3','Receiver location':'Area 1','Delivery status':'In Transit','Shipping cost':270}}


d2 = {1:'Phillip',2:'Omega lll',3 :'Ramya',4:'Romesh',5:'John'}

result = {}
for key, value in d1.items():
    new_value = {k: d2[v] if k in ('Sender', 'Receiver') else v for k,v in value.items()}
    result[key] = new_value
        
print(result)
```

Or, you can also use dictionary comprehension to calculate all this:

```
result = {key:{k: d2[v] if k in ('Sender', 'Receiver') else v for k,v in value.items()} for key, value in d1.items()}
```

Comment: I have to do it using Dictionary comprehension

Comment: I have edited the answer to use dictionary comprehension.

Answer (score 0):

You can use enumerate()

```
ship_info_alt = {k:[client_data[v] if ind in (0, 1) else v for ind, v in enumerate(v)] for k, v in ship_info.items()}
```